# r replace values not equal to 1 or 2 or 3 with other

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset with column `Race` with the following distribution below

```
  table(df$Race, useNA = "ifany")

  4      5     6     7   Asian   Black White  <NA> 
  15     6     11    29  1471    363   5917   5095
```

I am trying to replace values that are not White, Black or Asian with "Other"

```
    Asian   Black White  Other
    1471    363   5917   5156
```

Any suggestion on how to change values that are not White, Black or Asian to Other is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df$Race2 = replace(x = df$Race, 
                   list =  !df$Race %in% c('Asian', 'Black', 'White'), 
                   values =  'Other')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[!(Race %like% "Black" | Race %like% "Asian" | Race %like% "White"),Race:="Other"]
```

OR

```
setDT(dt)[!(Race == "Black" | Race == "Asian" | Race == "White"), Race:="Other"]
```